# Tongfang GK5CN6Z Ubuntu Touchpad and keyboard backlight

Tags: touchpad, backlight

I just bought a Tongfang GK5CN6Z and I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 4.15.0-33, but the touchpad and the keyboard backlight isn't working.

And I can't find anything about it on the net.

Can anyone help me?

I think it is not recognized.

```
i2c_hid: probe of i2c-UNIW0001:00 failed with error -1

Caminho do hardware  Dispositivo      Classe         Descrição
================================================================
                                      system         1540 (3044407)
/0                                    bus            GK5CN6Z
/0/0                                  memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/3a                                 memory         16GiB Memória do sistema
/0/3a/0                               memory         16GiB SODIMM DDR4 Síncrono 2667 MHz (0,4 ns)
/0/3a/1                               memory         Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS
/0/3a/2                               memory         Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS
/0/3a/3                               memory         Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS
/0/45                                 memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/46                                 memory         1536KiB L2 cache
/0/47                                 memory         9MiB L3 cache
/0/48                                 processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
/0/100                                bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1                              bridge         Skylake PCIe Controller (x16)
/0/100/1/0                            display        GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
/0/100/2                              display        Intel Corporation
/0/100/8                              generic        Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
/0/100/12                             generic        Intel Corporation
/0/100/14                             bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/14/0          usb1             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/2                         generic        USB2.0-CRW
/0/100/14/0/6                         input          ITE Device(8291)
/0/100/14/0/c                         input          MO4v2 Gaming Mouse                :
/0/100/14/0/d                         multimedia     HD Webcam
/0/100/14/0/e                         communication  Interface sem fio bluetooth
/0/100/14/1          usb2             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                           memory         RAM memory
/0/100/14.3          wlo1             network        Intel Corporation
/0/100/15                             bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/16                             communication  Intel Corporation
/0/100/17                             storage        Intel Corporation
/0/100/1b                             bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1b/0                           storage        Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
/0/100/1d                             bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1d/0                           storage        Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
/0/100/1d.5                           bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1d.5/0        enp4s0           network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1e                             communication  Intel Corporation
/0/100/1e.3                           bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f                             bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.3                           multimedia     Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.4                           bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.5                           bus            Intel Corporation
/0/1                 scsi0            storage        
/0/1/0.0.0           /dev/sda         disk           1TB ST1000LX015-1U71
/0/1/0.0.0/1         /dev/sda1        volume         931GiB Windows NTFS volume
/1                                    power          To Be Filled By O.E.M.
/2                   docker0          network        Ethernet interface
/3                   br-0c1d2a2e792d  network        Ethernet interface
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm developing a **open-source** project to control rgb backlit keyboards from a Brazilian company called Avell, which uses this same **ITE 8291 device,** so I'm pretty sure it's going to solve your problem, below is the project link and some usage instructions:

**clone repo:**

```
git clone https://github.com/rodgomesc/avell-unofficial-control-center.git
```

**go to project folder, revert for this day commit and install requirements.txt (if you not have python3-pip installed, search how to install it):**

```
cd avell-unofficial-control-center && git checkout ed05cbbd6a8c616257001b987b6e96ea3b8bf0d6 && sudo -H pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

**All commands to handle main.py need root permissions (you may use sudo).
Colors available are: red, green, blue, teal, pink, yellow, orange and white.**

```
sudo python main.py -c green -b 4
```

**if you want to disable the leds:**

```
sudo python main.py -d
```

the result:

[image: KeyBoard RGB Gren]

Happy hacking :)

Comment: I can confirm it works nice for tongfang GK5CQ7Z as it should for every Express ITE Device(8291) keyboard. No more forced deep blue keyboard lighting on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

The 4.19 kernel has the patch applied and it seems that everything is working properly

**Old response**

There is a bug open in https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=200787 about the trackpad problem.

I have the same laptop and I was able to install the patched kernel following the steps from the comment of Simon Detheridge at 2018-09-16 13:39:22 UTC.

Basically:

- Remove any package of the 4.15.0.34 kernel version (image, module, headers...)
- Download the .deb files from http://sd.ai/ubuntu-linux/
- Install it with `dpkg -i linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-34-generic_4.15.0-34.37_amd64.deb linux-modules-* linux-headers-*`
- Reboot using the new kernel

If installation fails, you can try to compile and patch the kernel yourself, but the easy option is above.

About the backlight problem, I think there is no solution yet.

You have more info on this topic from PcSpecialist, who sell the same laptop as "Recoil II": https://www.pcspecialist.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?59216-Linux-on-Recoil-ll

Comment: Is the backlight working now?

Answer (score 0):

lshw|grep ITE

```
                     product: ITE Device(8291)

                     vendor: ITE Tech. Inc.
```

uname -a

Linux ghost 5.18.3-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jun 9 16:11:39 CEST 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux

python main.py -c green -b 4

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/src/avell-unofficial-control-center/aucc/main.py", line 214, in 
main()
File "/usr/src/avell-unofficial-control-center/aucc/main.py", line 165, in main
control = ControlCenter(vendor_id=0x048d, product_id=0xce00)
File "/usr/src/avell-unofficial-control-center/aucc/main.py", line 104, in **init**
super(ControlCenter, self).**init**(vendor_id, product_id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/avell_unofficial_control_center-1.0.4-py3.10.egg/aucc/core/handler.py", line 50, in **init**
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/avell_unofficial_control_center-1.0.4-py3.10.egg/aucc/core/handler.py", line 16, in **init**
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/avell_unofficial_control_center-1.0.4-py3.10.egg/aucc/core/handler.py", line 27, in _get_device
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_kernel_driver_active'